# Weird spacing with mdframed

Tags: spacing, mdframed

I'm using mdframed to make a framed theorem environment but I'm having some trouble with the spacing below the theorem. This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks]{ntheorem}

\usepackage[ntheorem]{mdframed}
\mdfdefinestyle{thm}{ % saving some space
skipabove=3cm,
skipbelow=3cm,
splittopskip=\topskip,
splitbottomskip=\topskip
}
\newmdtheoremenv[style=thm]{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
Text above.
\begin{thm}
A theorem.
\end{thm}
Text below.
\end{document}
```

I want the spacing above and below the theorem to be the same but it isn't and changing `skipbelow` doesn't seem to have any effect.

Can anybody explain to me why what I am doing is wrong?

Comment: It seems a *bug* of the `mdframed` package and its `mdframed` environment, but i am not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an alternative solution using `tcolorbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks]{ntheorem}

\usepackage[theorems,breakable]{tcolorbox}%

%%% Defining through styles
\tcbset{
defstyle/.style={fonttitle=\bfseries\upshape, fontupper=\slshape,
arc=0mm, colback=blue!5!white,colframe=blue!75!black},
thmstyle/.style={fonttitle=\bfseries\upshape, fontupper=\slshape,
colback=red!10!white,colframe=red!75!black,before=\par\vspace{3cm}\noindent,after=\vspace{3cm}},
}
\newtcbtheorem[number within=subsection]{Definition}{Definition}{defstyle}{def}
\newtcbtheorem[use counter from=Definition]{thm}{Theorem}{thmstyle}{thm}

%% defining directly
\newtcbtheorem{lem}{Lemma}{%
        theorem name,%
        colback=green!5,%
        colframe=green!35!black,%
        fonttitle=\bfseries,title after break={Theorem  -- \raggedleft Continued}%
    }{lem}


\begin{document}
Text above.
\begin{thm}{A theorem.}{thm:mine}%
Some theorem here
\end{thm}
Text below.
\begin{lem}{A lemma.}{lem:mine}%
Some lemma here
\end{lem}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I prefer `tcolorbox` since it is more advanced and feature rich.

Comment: Thank you. I think there is a bug in mdframed so I will look into this package.